# Got error when installing flutter release build in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, dart, codesign

I was trying to install release build in iOS using testflight and it didn't work. In debug mode it works fine. So, I tried installing the build using the command "flutter run --release". I am getting an error like this:

```
vivekantony@ec2-100-31-0-47 finish-line-my-door % flutter run --release
Launching lib/main.dart on GS - SY-BU - iPhone14 - 1 in release mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: .........
Running Xcode build...                                                  
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         3.4s
Xcode build done.                                           19.2s
Error executing devicectl: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
13:11:58  Acquired tunnel connection to device.
13:11:58  Enabling developer disk image services.
13:11:58  Acquired usage assertion.
1%... 2%... 3%... 4%... 5%... 6%... 7%... 9%... 10%... 11%... 12%... 13%... 14%... 15%... 16%... 18%... 19%... 20%... 21%... 22%... 23%... 24%... 25%... 26%... 27%...
28%... 30%... 31%... 32%... 33%... 34%... 35%... 36%... 37%... 38%... 39%... 40%... 41%... 42%... 43%... 44%... 45%... 46%... 47%... 48%... 49%... 50%... 51%... 52%...
53%... 54%... 55%... 56%... 57%... 59%... 60%... 62%... 66%... 68%...

ERROR: Failed to install the app on the device. (com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError error 3002.)
         NSURL = file:///Users/vivekantony/Documents/flutter_projects/"Project Name"/build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app/
       ----------------------------------------
       Unable to Install “App Name” (IXUserPresentableErrorDomain error 14.)
         NSLocalizedFailureReason = This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified.
         NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = Failed to install embedded profile for "App bundle id" : 0xe800801f (Attempted to install a Beta profile without the proper
         entitlement.)
       ----------------------------------------
       Failed to install embedded profile for "App bundle id" : 0xe800801f (Attempted to install a Beta profile without the proper entitlement.) (MIInstallerErrorDomain
       error 13.)
         LegacyErrorString = ApplicationVerificationFailed
         LibMISErrorNumber = -402620385
         SourceFileLine = 200
         FunctionName = -[MIInstallableBundle _installEmbeddedProfilesWithError:]
  Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun devicectl device install app --device 00008110-000218DE0E88201E build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app --json-output
  /var/folders/t9/fd5ddx_d26z6wxnrcf9zfzyw0000gp/T/flutter_tools.pWKwuv/core_devices.c6jZDF/install_results.json
Could not run build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on 00008110-000218DE0E88201E.
Try launching Xcode and selecting "Product > Run" to fix the problem:
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
```

Have anybody encountered this issue before?

It was working before and I changed the bundle id and created new provision profiles for Debug and Release modes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this issue by selecting "Automatically manage signing" and running the command "flutter run --release".